# Remove doublequotes in json format file

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to convert the below JSON format file to the output format mentioned below(I am basically trying to remove the double quotes from the attribute names like GroupId..) in javascript. Does anyone have any suggestion on this?

**Input Format**:

```
{ 
  "GroupId": "sg-1234556", 
  "GroupName": "sggroupname",
  "IpPermissions": [ 
   {             
     "FromPort": 9090, 
     "ToPort": 9090, 
     "IpProtocol": "tcp", 
     "IpRanges": [ { "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0" } ] 
 }]
}
```

**Output Format**:

```
var params = {
        GroupId: "sg-1234556",
        GroupName: "sggroupname",
        IpPermissions: [
               {
                    FromPort: 9090,
                    ToPort: 9090,
                    IpProtocol: "tcp",
                    IpRanges: [{
                            CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
                                }],
                }]
    }
```

Comment: Question: why do the keys on your object need the double quotes removed? In JavaScript they won't affect anything. `params.GroupId` is the same thing as `params["GroupId"]`

Comment: Why would you need to do that? Is valid with or without quotes

Comment: Removing the quotes from keys will cause problems if any of the keys have special characters that aren't allowed in identifiers.

Comment: Thanks all for your response. To be more specific this is a nodejs script created to run as a AWS lambda fuction. I call params object in a function to do a remove operation and it works only if the attributes(like GroupID, GroupName, FromPort, ToPort ..) are NOT enclosed in double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using regexp**

```js
var object = {
  "GroupId": "sg-1234556",
  "GroupName": "sggroupname",
  "IpPermissions": [{
    "FromPort": 9090,
    "ToPort": 9090,
    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
    "IpRanges": [{
      "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
    }]
  }]
};

var regexp = /"(\w+)"\s*:/g;
var group = '$1:';

var result = JSON.stringify(object, null, 2).replace(regexp, group);

console.log(result);
```